# Runtime error: MongoDB::DatabaseError: bad hint

Tags: mongodb, perl

I am trying to call the [`hint` method on a `MongoDB::Cursor` object](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB::Cursor#hint). However, it throwing an exception when it's trying to execute the query. See the code sample below:

```
sub some_method_which_returns_cursor {

  my $cursor = $collection->find($filter);

  if ($hint) {
    $cursor->hint({‘some_index’ => 1});  #failing here.
  }

  if ($sort) {
    $cursor->sort($sort);
  }

   return $cursor;
}
```

Any thoughts as to what's going on and how I can fix this?

Comment: Is this your real code? It's invalid: `$cursor->hint({ some_index => 1} );`

Comment: Don't use **‘** and **’** as quotation marks in a program. Or, to put it differently, don't write your programs using a word processor. Also, what is **`If`**?! What is **defined-or** (i.e., **`//`**) doing after a statement?!

Comment: @Borodin `ghd` is apparently my way of typing *`the`*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harish asked me via email and I'll repeat my answer here for posterity:

The `hint` method takes a *string* when given an index name, or an *array reference* when given keys/order pairs:

```
$cursor->hint("some_index");                # by name
$cursor->hint([field1 => 1, field2 => -1]); # by keys
```

It also takes a hash reference, but don't use that because modern Perls randomize key order when serializing, so your hint may not match an index.

Comment: BTW, this doesn't work on MongoDB perl driver version 0.45. Works on v1.8.0 though. @xdg